# Accessing jQuery UI Dialog options object at runtime

Tags: jquery-ui

Is there a way for me to access the {options} object passed to a jQuery UI dialog constructor at runtime?  I need to play with options attributes such as maxHeight and some custom attributes that I pass too.  I should mention that I am using jQuery 2.0.3 with jQuery UI 1.10.3.  This appears to have broken the technique I was using before

```
var $visible = $(".ui-dialog:visible");
$visible.each(function()
{
 var $this = $(this);
 var dialog = $this.find(".ui-dialog-content").data("dialog");
 //dialog.options - does not work any more since dialog turns up undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data key is 'ui-dialog', not 'dialog'.  Try this:

```
...
var dialog = $this.find('.ui-dialog-content').data('ui-dialog');
// Now you will have access to the dialog.options object
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gT9kv/)

**Update**

It looks like you can modify the options by calling the 'option' method and passing in a key and a value or an object of many key/value pairs:

```
$('.myDialog').dialog('option', 'height', 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  That did the trick.  I did try to examine find('.ui-dialog-content').data() but did not think of looking at the ui-dialog entry.